# Using previous MySQL data folder on new MySQL installation

Tags: mysql

If I could have made a proper `SQL dump/backup` I would have, but `OS` gave out and could only log into `SafeMode`, where I couldn't start the `MySQL server`. Therefore, I could only manually backup the file directories.

- I have a saved file copy of C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0
- I have a saved file copy of C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0

I'm now running on a new installation of `Windows` and trying to start this old server up for a few minutes so I can log on from `Workbench` and make a proper `SQL database dump` which will I `import` on a new `MySQL` installation later.

Consequently, moving the mentioned files in their respective locations - `Program Files` and `ProgramData`.

Opening up `PowerShell` (with Admin rights) and doing:

```
mysqld --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0" --console
```

and I get a few **hundred** lines on the screen that contain the following:

```
2020-04-10T05:28:56.725818Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011972] [InnoDB] Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html for information about forcing recovery.
2020-04-10T05:28:56.734460Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011971] [InnoDB] Tablespace 'innodb_undo_001' Page [page id: space=4294967279, page number=5] log sequence number 1339677380 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 19081380.
```

Followed by:

```
2020-04-10T05:28:56.740834Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011972] [InnoDB] Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html for information about forcing recovery.
2020-04-10T05:28:56.757259Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting crash recovery...
2020-04-10T05:28:56.769215Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] Crash recovery finished.
2020-04-10T05:28:57.695386Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-04-10T05:28:57.765911Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.13'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2020-04-10T05:28:57.926850Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060
```

Great, at least its running.

I can now `connect` but no `databases`.

- What can I do / how should I proceed to successfully get those databases back temporarily?

**UPDATE:**

Removed the innodb_undo_001 and innodb_undo_002 files from the Data directory and relaunched.

Getting this:

```
PS C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin> .\mysqld --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini" --console                                                               2020-04-10T05:55:29.555478Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010915] [Server] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2020-04-10T05:55:29.558313Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.13) starting as process 3028
2020-04-10T05:55:31.394427Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012351] [InnoDB] Tablespace 1, name 'sys/sys_config', file '.\sys\sys_config.ibd' is missing!
2020-04-10T05:55:32.808645Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-04-10T05:55:32.856154Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.13'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2020-04-10T05:55:32.898055Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060
```

***Running but no databases present.***

Tried the Innodb-force-recovery approach - nothing happens. Same as before.

Comment: Have you tried with [Innodb-force-recovery?](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html)

Comment: @tcadidot0 I did yes. Nothing. No errors, no recovery, no databases.

Comment: Do you have the full table info including `ibdata1` in the `MySQL 8.0/data` folder?

Comment: @tcadidot0 Yup. Windows crashed - 1 hr later I backed everything up so data is intact and all the folders and files are present and where they're supposed to be. Nothing is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, assuming that all the files are not corrupted, you can try the following:

1. Create a new folder (in a different drive if possible). Name it as `test` or something. Then copy all files from the `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0` directory into the new folder.

[image]

*note: if you don't have my.ini file in the folder, copy it from the `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0` directory into the folder.

2. Open my.ini file and change the following:
   [image]
3. Go back to the top of my.ini file and change:
   [image]
   after changing above, copy the whole line from `mysqld --install MySQLXY ..` to the end. Don't copy the first `#` at the beginning. Then save the my.ini file.
4. Open command prompt (cmd) as administrator then do this:
   [image]

*installing the service manually using cmd.

5. Go to services (keyboard shortcut windows button+R then type `services.msc` then press ENTER or OK), find the newly installed MySQL service and click `start`.
6. Try connecting to db.

Comment: Same thing. No databases showing up after connecting to the server with Workbench. The server runs, no errors.

Comment: What does it log into the *.err file?

Comment: Hey there, sorry about the delay, Easter holidays and all. I've awarded the bounty since you put some effort in your answer and might help someone else down the line with a similar issue. Like I said previously, it throws NO ERRORS - everything (including by way of your explanation) works fine in the sense that the server installs as a service, starts up, I can connect to it, and so forth. What I'm saying is it doesn't show me ANY of the databases it should - like its ignoring them completely. It's acting as a fresh, new installation without any databases. I'll keep looking, thanks!

Comment: I'm just afraid that it's unrecoverable. I've had that experience a few times before and since then I kept this link just in case, maybe this will help you https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16875/restore-table-from-frm-and-ibd-file/16911#16911 .

Comment: Could be. Yup, that's what I came across also while searching these past few days. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score -1):

Check your mysql config file. Make sure the datadir goes to the correct folder (C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0) or wherever you saved put that now