# Recover MySQL data from windows.old

Tags: mysql, sql, restore, recover

My SO (Windows 10) stopped working and so I had to format the disk.
The archives have been stored at the Windows.old folder.

Saddly, I've never made any backup of MySQL database and now I need to know if is there any way to restore the data from that MySQL folder stored at Windows.old

Does anybody know if is it possible and how could I make it?

I've tried to replace the MySQL Server 8.0 folder at ProgramData\MySQL, but then the server doesn't start.

Comment: See if this could help https://stackoverflow.com/a/61262477/10910692

Comment: The data isn't stored in your Windows directory. It's in a different location that depends on which MySQL installer you used.